# PHP REST API not accepting image if using header('Content-Type: application/json') but working without images

Tags: php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
if( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['mobile']) ){

    $biz_name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));
    $biz_phone = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['mobile']));   
    $biz_banner = $_FILES['imagebanner']['name'];
    $biz_banner_tmp = $_FILES['imagebanner']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($biz_banner_tmp, "../profile_banner/$biz_phone.jpg");
    echo "acknowledgement";     
    exit();

}
```

i'm using postman rest client service to check this, if i choose form-data and using its not working but its working with x-www-form-urlencoded.
i think im stuck with header();

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working? Also, you're open to all kinds of nasty injections here. `mysql_real_escape_string` is ***not*** going to prevent somebody from uploading something evil. It would be pretty easy to do all sorts of awful things to your server with this code.

Comment: I second the comment by Ed Cottrell, and I also think that you're mixing up the request and the response.
When you call the header method, you're altering the response, whereas setting the submitted data to x-www-form-urlencoded is on the request side, so it's not really related.

Comment: i'm trying to update name in database table based on phone number so i'm sending both, along with name i want to update his profile image too. so nothing happens when i'm sending data from postman and using form-data option in body.

Comment: The **response**-`header` you send there has nothing to do with how the data is sent from your frontend/Postman to this endpoint. For forms with files you generally should set `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ... >`

Comment: What @JacobRasmussen said. The value in the `enctype` of your `<form>` tag should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, as in `<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">`. That has nothing to do with what you set in this `header` call.

Comment: yes we can achieve the result by send data from form tag by using multipart/form-data. but we need to make the rest api for android application, the rest api written in php, that rest api calling by android application. So in php rest api, what content type should i mention other than header('Content-Type: application/json'); i have to send input type text and file both.